# Range bar in redux form

Tags: reactjs, range, redux-form

i have a range bar which i create from react-slider. I want to use it in a redux-form. My problem is that the values are not returning. To be more specific when i sumbit my form the other fields return values while this range bar returns undefined. How do i have to use the Range in a redux-form?? My code is

```
<FormGroup className="col-sm-3 ">
        <Label for="value-slider">VALUE</Label>{' '}
        <Field
          id="value-slider"
          name="value-slider"
          component={Range}
        />
      </FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass any random component to `component` prop. It must implement interface of redux-form (see [usage](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/#usage)), what `Range` does not. In short, passed element must at least trigger event with `input.onChange` and display value from `input.value` prop:

```js
const MyRange = props => (
  <Range value={props.input.value} onChange={props.input.onChange} />
)
```

And then use it:

```js
<Field
  id="value-slider"
  name="value-slider"
  component={MyRange}
/>
```

Comment: Im writing import React from 'react';
import { Range } from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';

const MyRange = (props) => {
  const value = props.input.value;
  const onChange = props.input.onChange;

  return (
    <Range value={value} onChange={onChange} />
  );
};


export default MyRange; An error is showing value.map is not a function.. Do you know what it means?

Comment: I ran into this error, too. I've posted the fix as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue just now, thanks to maddox2 for the answer which set me along the right lines, however, as one user pointed out in the comments above, the solution above will give `TypeError: value.map is not a function`.

To fix this, you need to explicitly set the type of the field in `initialValues`, when you use `reduxForm()`to create the form. Example code is below.

Note how additional props used by `Range` are also passed to `ReduxRange` in the `props` prop, and that these are then passed down to the `Range` in the wrapping component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

import Range from 'rc-slider/lib/Range';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';

// initial wrapper - note alterations
const ReduxRange = props => {
    const { input: { value, onChange } } = props
    return (
        <Range
            value={props.input.value}
            onChange={props.input.onChange}
            {...props}
        />
    )
}


// the form
export const SomeReduxForm = props => {
    const { handleSubmit } = props;
    // these props will get passed to the Range
    const rangeProps = {
        defaultValue:[2020, 2040],
        marks:{
            2020: '2020',
            2030: '2030',
            2040: '2040',
            2050: '2050',
            2060: '2060',
            2070: '2070',
            2080: '2080',
        },
        pushable:true,
        allowCross:false,
        min:2018,
        max:2080,
        step:1,
    }
    return (
        <section className="box box-default">
            <form>
                <div className="box-header">Year Range</div>
                <div className="box-body">
                    <Field
                        name="yearRange"
                        component={ReduxRange}
                        props={rangeProps}
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    )
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'someReduxForm',
    initialValues: {
        yearRange: [2020, 2040]
    }
})(SomeReduxForm)
```